# Update object in array using useState and a button

Tags: react-hooks

I have a list of users That I want to maintain,
I was able to delete a user from the list and add a new user to the list,
But I can not update an existing user.

import {useState} from 'react'

const ChildComp = ()=>
{
const [users,setUsers] = useState([{name:"Leanne " ,age : "40", city : "Gwenborough",},
{name:"Ervin " ,age : "35", city : "Wisokyburgh",},
{name:"Clementine " ,age : "22", city : "McKenziehaven",}])

```
const [user,setUser] = useState({name : "" , age : 0, city :""})
const [deletUser,setDeletUser] = useState ("")



const deletMe =() =>
{
    let array = [...users]
    let index = array.findIndex(item=>item.name===deletUser)
  
    if (index!==-1)
    {
        array.splice(index,1)
        setUsers(array)
    }
}

const Update = (e) =>
{
    
   
   let array = [...users]
    let index = array.findIndex(item=>item.name===deletUser)
  
    if (index!==-1)
    {
        array.splice(index,1)
        setUsers(array)
        setUsers([...users,user])
       
    }

    
}


return(<div>
    <h1>add user  </h1>

    Name :  <input type ="text" onChange = {e=> setUser({...user,name:e.target.value})}/><br/>
    Age :  <input type ="text" onChange = {e=> setUser({...user,age:e.target.value})}/><br/>
    City :  <input type ="text" onChange = {e=> setUser({...user,city:e.target.value})}/><br/>

    <input type = "button" value ="Add" onClick ={e=>setUsers([...users,user])}/>
    <input type ="button" value = "Update" onClick = {Update}/><br/>

    <h3>Delet user  </h3>

    <input type = "text" name = "dleteUser" onChange = {e=>setDeletUser(e.target.value)}/>
    <input type ="button" value = "DELET" onClick = {deletMe}/><br/>
    
    <table border = "1">
   {users.map((item,index) =>
   {
       return <tr key = {index}>
           <td > {item.name}  </td>
           <td > {item.age}  </td>
           <td > {item.city}  </td>
       </tr>
   })}
   </table>
   
    </div>
    )
```

}
export default ChildComp;

Comment: Your code isn’t well formatted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update a user by first getting the index of this user in the array, then update the element in the array, then return the array :

```
const update = (e) => {
    setUsers(users => {
        const index = users.findIndex(item => item.name === user.name);

        if (index === -1) { 
            return […users, user];
        }

        users[index] = user;
        return users;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use "deletUser" within your Update function although that variable is only set when clicking the "DELET"-Button.
What you want to use is the user-variable that is set whenever you're changing one of the upper input-fields.

Here's some example code that updates a user entry

```js
const Update = () => {
  setUsers(
    users.map((existingUser) => {
      return existingUser.name === user.name 
        ? user 
        : existingUser;
    })
  );
};
```

p.s.: As your input-strings are suffixed with a space ("Leanne ") you would have to write "Leanne " in your input field to change the first entry.